# Cannot find Desktop Sharing in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

Is there anyone knows how to find Desktop Sharing in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?
Is it possible that this feature is only available for Server version?

Thanks

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 2):

ok, I find out the answer by myself. Actually, I need to install vino. After that, once I execute vino-preferences in a terminal, then the Desktop Sharing is show up.